# Manage MSDS in Sharepoint document library

Tags: document-library, document, sharepoint-search, picture-library, document-info-panel

I want to manage MSDS in SP document library
Requirements:

1. IDH (Unique Number for each material) - Total MSDS count will be 200*3+ Picture (200No.)
2. Supplier 1
3. Supplier 2
4. Supplier 3
5. Attach Valid MSDS 3 suppliers (Validity of MSDS is 3 years from print/ Origin date) - Trigger required when document id out of date.
6. Photo of the product (Master sample photo) - (Need to be seen live, not as file name)
7. Search Index, with name, IDH or Finished good name (to provide list of RM goes to that FG)- Can be made and updated in separate list

Is this database can be made in SP?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried. What is your question? Where are you stuck? Uploading a list of your requirements does not constitute a question.

Comment: Hello Matthew. I haven't started doing it. I would like to know if this is possible in SP. Im not a SP designer, im a enthusiastic, trying to make it.

Comment: It is definitely possible. It may actually be easier to aggregate it visually with a PowerApp.